# convert getch() response to ascii character

Tags: c++, ascii, centos

I am using ncurses on linux. I use getch() to get the next key pressed from the input stream but it returns a number not a letter.

After doing research on google I have found that getch() is not standard so I am at a loss of what to do.

I need the keys 0-9, tab, ctrl, p,v,m,l,a,b,c,d,e,f, and the arrow keys as well as 0xff, 0x4F00, 0x4700, 0x4800, 0x5000, 0x4D00:, 0x4B00, 0x4900, 0x5100. These are what are uses in if statments against the returned valus of getch().

this is the code in the windows version of the program am trying to recreate.

```
    unsigned long nr;
if( GetNumberOfConsoleInputEvents(ConH,&nr) )
{
    if( nr > 0 )
    {
        INPUT_RECORD ipr;
        ReadConsoleInput(ConH,&ipr,1,&nr);
        if( ipr.EventType == KEY_EVENT && ipr.Event.KeyEvent.bKeyDown )
        {
            int key = ipr.Event.KeyEvent.uChar.AsciiChar;
            if( key == 0 ) key = ipr.Event.KeyEvent.wVirtualScanCode<<8;
            return key;
        }
    }
}
return 0;
```

Is there a function i can use on the result of getch() so i can get the actual key pressed, something like the .AsciiChar seen above ?

Comment: have you tried assigning the value to a char and then outputting it and see what it is?

Comment: @PlasmaHH yes, the letters, numbers and tab keys print as single numbers, the arrow keys print as three numbers.

Comment: Then you print out the int. Assign them to a char variable and print out the char as a char like: `char c= getch(); std::cout << c;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**MAJOR EDIT** Get rid of previous examples, try this large one.

The return value from `getch()` is either an ASCII character, or the curses name for some special key.

Here is a program that might make the point clear:

```
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <cctype>

int main(int ac, char **av) 
{
    WINDOW* mainWin(initscr());
    cbreak();
    noecho();

    // Invoke keypad(x, true) to ensure that arrow keys produce KEY_UP, et al,
    // and not multiple keystrokes.
    keypad(mainWin, true);

    mvprintw(0, 0, "press a key: ");
    int ch;

    // Note that getch() returns, among other things, the ASCII code of any key
    // that is pressed. Notice that comparing the return from getch with 'q'
    // works, since getch() returns the ASCII code 'q' if the users presses that key.
    while( (ch = getch()) != 'q' ) {
      erase();
      move(0,0);
      if(isascii(ch)) {
        if(isprint(ch)) {
          // Notice how the return code (if it is ascii) can be printed either
          // as a character or as a numeric value.
          printw("You pressed a printable ascii key: %c with value %d\n", ch, ch);
        } else {
          printw("You pressed an unprintable ascii key: %d\n", ch);
        }
      }

      // Again, getch result compared against an ASCII value: '\t', a.k.a. 9
      if(ch == '\t') {
        printw("You pressed tab.\n");
      }

      // For non-ASCII values, use the #define-s from <curses.h>
      switch(ch) {
      case KEY_UP:
        printw("You pressed KEY_UP\n");
        break;
      case KEY_DOWN:
        printw("You pressed KEY_DOWN\n");
        break;
      case KEY_LEFT:
        printw("You pressed KEY_LEFT\n");
        break;
      case KEY_RIGHT:
        printw("You pressed KEY_RIGHT\n");
        break;
      }
      printw("Press another key, or 'q' to quit\n");
      refresh();
    }

    endwin();
}
```

**References**:

- http://linux.die.net/man/3/getch
- http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/
- http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/keys.html
- http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/keys.html

Comment: tab returns 9, the arrow keys return three numbers, up for instance is 27, 91, 65 and at no point do you answer the question which is how to translate a ascii code into a letter. I dont want to know if its a valid key I want 14 to be changer into g.

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought the code I posted made that all clear. The tab key returns 9, which is also known as `'\t'`. So the statement `if(ch == '\t') return ch;` is equivalent to `if(ch == 9) return '\t';`.  Similarly, the line `if(isascii(ch)) return ch;` translates the ascii code into a letter. As for arrows, I thought `getch()` collected the three-character escape sequence and translated it into `KEY_UP`. I'm not sure why your program isn't behaving that way.

Comment: @Skeith: There is no "translate a ascii code into a letter" in C++, char is an integral type, so when you want a char "g" then you do `char c = 'g';` but for ascii this is equivalent to `char c = 103;` (and you can do the opposite by outputting chars like: `std::cout << +'g';`)

Comment: @Skeith, see my edit. This is a complete program you can download, compile and run. Notice the equivalence between integer values and character codes. Notice also what is printed when you hit 'tab'. Finally, notice the call to `keypad()`. If you still have questions, please continue to respond.

Comment: @RobThank you for taking the extra time to help. i think where i went wrong was this line in the original code "int key = ipr.Event.KeyEvent.uChar.AsciiChar;" made me think it was changing int to char but it looks like it getting some microsoft type and making it ascii.

Comment: In gnome-terminal (U13.10) on my laptop, *ncurses* reports the `~` key (0x7e) when I press `numpad HOME`, but the arrows and page up/down work fine.  When I use XTERM, it all works ok.  This leads me to believe it has something to do with gnome-terminal's *terminfo* database.  I tried using `gconf-editor` but it only allows me to create short-cuts for keybindings.
I'm wondering if anyone knows how to fix this?